# Labeling sentences and words

Tags: labels, ref

Is there an easy way to label a sentence or a word inside a document to reference it somewhere else, something like an internal, invisible label?
I mean I could also put it into a subsection and write \subsection{Abc}\label{chap:abc}, but is there a smarter way without embedding it into a section?

Comment: You talk about "reference" and "bookmark", which are very different things. What exactly should be printed?

Comment: I mean references. I did not mean bookmark in a LaTeX-way, I was just thinking of bookmarks when I wrote that, sorry.I will correct the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hyperlinks (`hyperref` package):

```
\hyperlink{myword}{that word}
\hypertarget{myword}{this word}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works